# Counter() function in for loop looks odd

Tags: python-3.x, counter

I have a list of sequences to be found in the sequencing data. So I run a for loop to find the match sequences in a dataset, and used Counter() to get the maximum sequences. But I found the Counter() function would add previous loop data, not as separate one.

ls = ['AGC', 'GCT', 'TAC', 'CGT']

dataset.txt like a bunch of sequences of "AGTAGCTTT", "AGTTAGC"......

```
def xfind(seq):
    ls2 = []
    with open(dataset.txt, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if seq in line:
            ls2.append(line)

    import collections
    from collections import Counter
    cnt = Counter()
    for l in ls2:
        cnt[l] += 1
    print (cnt.most_common()[0])

for l2 in ls:
    xfind(l2)
```

The results look like:
('AGTAGCTTT", 2)
('AGTAGCTTT", 5)

It should be:
('AGTAGCTTT', 2)
('GCT...', 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you understand your code very well and your use of `Counter` isn't really how it's intended to be used I think.

You start by checking if the substring is in the sequence (`line`) for each line of the text file, and if it is you add it to a list `ls2`

Then for every element of that list (which are the whole lines/sequences from the text file) you add 1 to the counter for that key. You do this in a loop, when the whole point of `Counter` is that you can simply call:

`cnt = Counter(ls2)`

This all means that you are reporting the most common sequence in the file, which also contains the given subsequence.

Now it is actually a bit hard to say what your exact output should be, without knowing what your `dataset.txt` looks like.

I would start by tidying up the code a little:

```
from collections import Counter

subsequences = ['AGC', 'GCT', 'TAC', 'CGT']

def xfind(subseq):
    contains_ss = []
    with open("dataset.txt", 'r') as f:
       for line in f:
           if subseq in line:
               contains_ss.append(line)
    cnt = Counter(contains_ss)
    print(cnt.most_common()[0])

for ss in subsequences:
    xfind(ss)
```